# Calling a function on a different control

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a User Control with with some search functionality, then I also have a control that contains a grid. In the control that has the grid I have all the functionality to retrieve some items I need to populate a report from the search control.

My question is, and I have read about this but not completely sure how to make it work, I read i need to register a event handler in control A that calls the function in control B. How does that work?

Say in control B there is a function that I need to call  `GetAllItemsByRegistrantID(int id).` How can I make a call to this function from control A?

I would really appreciate any help or guidance on this.

Regards

Comment: Yes both are, thank you for asking this, I forgot to mention it

Comment: The answer to this question will tell you how to define the custom event, then you need to wire up a handler to it on your page. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998479/explain-code-for-custom-event-in-user-control

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here is an example if you had to do it using events.](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/9659390/TestUserControls.zip)

On your first user control (the search control) define a custom event.

```
public partial class UserControl1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public event EventHandler<MyCustomeEventArgs> MyCustomClickEvent;

    protected virtual void OnMyCustomClickEvent(MyCustomeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MyCustomClickEvent != null)
            MyCustomClickEvent(this, e);

    }

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnMyCustomClickEvent(new MyCustomeEventArgs(5));
    }

}
public class MyCustomeEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public MyCustomeEventArgs(int searchID)
    {
        SearchID = searchID;
    }
    public int SearchID { get; set; }

}
```

On your user control with the grid, define a handler.

```
public void HandleCustomEvent(object sender, MyCustomeEventArgs e)
{
    GetAllItemsByRegistrantID(e.SearchID);
}

public void GetAllItemsByRegistrantID(int id)
{
    Label1.Text = id.ToString();
}
```

On the page where they both live, wire them together.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserControl1Instance.MyCustomClickEvent += UserControl2Instance.HandleCustomEvent;
}
```

Comment: It's late so I am not thinking too clearly but in this case, isn't UserControl1 and UserControl2 referring to the classes themselves and not the instance of the classes on the page?

Comment: No, that's me having named the instances of the controls the same thing as the class.  I'll modify it in the answer to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely try and avoid this sort of situation. You should be putting this sort of code in a class and sharing this between the two controls.

Comment: Lets suppose I do not have an option and this is already code being used this way and have to commit to do what am I told, how can I still do this?

Comment: I had just typed up a chunk of addition text explaining why this is not a good idea and you just blew the wind out of my sails with this comment :). You will need to hook up the instances of one of the controls to the other. It would be easiest if you create the control programatically.